# Does stun from artillery disable crew perks?

Tags: world-of-tanks

It has happened to me sometimes that I get hit by artillery without the 6th sense light bulb popping up, on a spot that is totally not obvious for blind-firing.

As the crew stun lowers effectiveness of the crew, does this mean that it also disables perks on crew members?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't affect perks according to the [Update 9.18 bulletin](https://worldoftanks.com/en/news/general-news/918-spg-revision/):

> ... tanks in the arty burst radius ... have their *characteristics temporarily weakened*.

This leads to the question, "How you can get hit by artillery without a 6th Sense alert?" Possibilities include:

1. Counter-battery fire - When in bird's-eye-view artillery can see your tracers anywhere on the map and blind-fire at the source.  See [this video](https://youtu.be/alsJAxcCHDo?t=326) for an example. A teammate on arty's side, maybe somebody you're firing on, could guess your location and point to a map square for arty to watch.
2. Breaking things like trees/fences/poles/buildings/etc. or moving destroyed tanks because these are visible in bird's eye view.
3. If you were spotted earlier and didn't become unspotted 6th Sense doesn't alert you that you're still spotted. (Obvious but worth mentioning.)

Comment: Add breaking environment elements. Trees, fences etc. Or other hints: teammates bumping into you, teammates hiding behind you / driving from behind you to take a shot, bumping into a hull of dead tank, etc. Add to that 5s delay between getting spotted and getting the 6th sense warning.

Comment: @SF - Did you see the 5s delay documented somewhere? I believe it's 3s based on the [WoT wiki| Crew Perks](http://wiki.wargaming.net/en/Crew#Perks) page. I've also seen 3s in the forums.

Comment: I think it was shortened from 5 to 3s sometime around the HD update.

Comment: BTW thanks for the "breaking things" suggestion @SF, I've updated my answer.